# Error Code: 1054 Unknown column error in Zend 1.12.8

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

One of my MySQL query is running perfectly OK in Zend 1.11.12 but not in Zend 1.12.8.
Query -

```
$query = $this->select()
             ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
             ->from(
                array('a' => 'tbcc_reports'), 
                array('report_id', 'report_code', 'report_heading', 
                      'report_description', 'report_page_name', 
                      'report_published_date', 'price_policy_id', 
                      'timestampdiff(month,report_published_date,now()) as interval')
                )
            ->join(
                array('b' => 'tbcc_price_policy_master'), 
                'a.price_policy_id = b.price_policy_id', 
                array(
                    'pr_price as price',
                    'CAST(reportPriceCalculator(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,a.report_published_date,NOW()), pr_price) AS UNSIGNED) AS realprice'
                )
            )
            ->join(
                array('c' => 'tbcc_authors'), 
                'a.primary_auth_id = c.author_id', 
                array('author_fname', 'author_lname')
            )
            ->where("(a.report_cat_id = $catId) AND a.report_status='1' AND a.report_parent_id=0")
            ->order($order);
```

I searched your forum and tried out the possible solutions listed but didn't succeed.
When I am printing the query it is coming like this -

````
SELECT `a`.`report_id`, `a`.`report_code`, `a`.`report_heading`, 
       `a`.`report_description`, `a`.`report_page_name`, `a`.`report_published_date`, 
       `a`.`timestampdiff(month,report_published_date,now())` AS `interval`, 
       `a`.`price_policy_id`, `b`.`pr_price` AS `price`, 
      `CAST(``reportPriceCalculator``(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,report_published_date,NOW()), ``b```.```pr_price``) AS UNSIGNED)` AS `realprice`, 
      `c`.`author_fname`, `c`.`author_lname`
FROM `tbcc_reports` AS `a` 
INNER JOIN `tbcc_price_policy_master` AS `b` ON a.price_policy_id = b.price_policy_id
INNER JOIN `tbcc_authors` AS `c` ON a.primary_auth_id = c.author_id 
WHERE ((a.report_cat_id = 1) AND a.report_status='1' AND a.report_parent_id=0) 
ORDER BY `a`.`report_published_date` DESC
````

If I change my query to -

```
SELECT `a`.`report_id`, `a`.`report_code`, `a`.`report_heading`, 
       `a`.`report_description`, `a`.`report_page_name`, `a`.`report_published_date`, 
       timestampdiff(month,a.report_published_date,now()) AS `interval`, 
       `a`.`price_policy_id`, `b`.`pr_price` AS `price`, 
       CAST(reportPriceCalculator(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,a.report_published_date,NOW()), b.pr_price) AS UNSIGNED) AS `realprice`, 
       `c`.`author_fname`, `c`.`author_lname` 
FROM `tbcc_reports` AS `a` 
INNER JOIN `tbcc_price_policy_master` AS `b` ON a.price_policy_id = b.price_policy_id 
INNER JOIN `tbcc_authors` AS `c` ON a.primary_auth_id = c.author_id 
WHERE ((a.report_cat_id = 2) AND a.report_status='1' AND a.report_parent_id=0) 
ORDER BY `report_published_date` DESC
```

It runs properly and lists me the details. I have not been able to implement the above query in the Zend based query.
Could you look into it?

Comment: Please edit your post, and use formatting options ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, some thoughouts about your code / question :

1- Writing a clean code is the first step to easy code debug.
2- Please take your time to write a "clear" question : You can easily see the difference between your posted question and how it appears now : This will bring more attention to your question.
3- Pay attention to SQL Injections by properly escaping your input (or using placeholders : See your original where method and the where method in my code below)

The problem in your query is that the DB Adapter is trying to quote identifiers in your query. As you can see : your `reportPriceCalculator` become `''reportPriceCalculator''`. To prevent any quotes added to your query, use `Zend_Db_Expr`.

Your query should become :

```
$query = $this->select()
                 ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                 ->from(
                    array('a' => 'tbcc_reports'), 
                    array('report_id', 'report_code', 'report_heading', 
                          'report_description', 'report_page_name', 
                          'report_published_date', 'price_policy_id', 
                          'timestampdiff(month,report_published_date,now()) as interval')
                    )
                ->join(
                    array('b' => 'tbcc_price_policy_master'), 
                    'a.price_policy_id = b.price_policy_id', 
                    array(
                        'price'     => 'pr_price',
                        'realprice' => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                            'CAST(reportPriceCalculator(TIMESTAMPDIFF(' 
                            . 'MONTH,a.report_published_date,NOW()), pr_price)'
                            . ' AS UNSIGNED)'
                        )
                    )
                )
                ->join(
                    array('c' => 'tbcc_authors'), 
                    'a.primary_auth_id = c.author_id', 
                    array('author_fname', 'author_lname')
                )
                ->where('a.report_cat_id = ?', $catId)
                ->where('a.report_status = 1')
                ->where('a.report_parent_id = 0')
                ->order($order);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi,

it is still showing problem at -

     'timestampdiff(month,report_published_date,now()) as interval')


       Runs fine on Zend 1.11.12 but not on Zend 1.12.8

Comment: @SumanttoB Use `Zend_Db_Expr` again. Change `'timestampdiff(month,report_published_date,now()) as interval'` to become `new Zend_Db_Expr('timestampdiff(month,report_published_date,now()) as interval')`.